# setInterval within for loop having separate instances in javascript Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am building an ionic app and within the constructor of component I have a loop that iterate through all the items. Within the loop I have written setInterval that calls a function from within as shown below.

```
var thisScope = this;
for (let i = 0; i < this.schedules.length; i++) {
    (function() {
      thisScope.showTime[i] = new Date();
      thisScope.showTime[i].setHours(0, 0, 0);
      thisScope.schedules[i].afh.timerIncDec = '00:00:00';
      if (!thisScope.timerFinish || AfhListviewComponent.timerInSeconds[i] !== 0 || thisScope.schedules[i].afh.timerIncDec != '00:00:00') {
        thisScope.timerId = setInterval(() => {          
            thisScope.timerTick(thisScope.schedules[i]);           
        }, 1000);
      } else if (thisScope.timerFinish || AfhListviewComponent.timerInSeconds[i] === 0 || thisScope.schedules[i].afh.timerIncDec === '00:00:00') {
        clearInterval(thisScope.timerId);
      }
    })();
  }
```

Here I want to set the timer (its calculations is being done within `timerTick` function). Here the problem I am facing is setInterval that is being overlapped and its speed gets increased less than `1000`. Each item of loop should maintain its own instance of `setInterval`. 
The variable that is being used as increment and decrement is `timerInSeconds` that is static written within same component.

Here the `1000` value is being overlapped by other setIntervals within same loop or same loop having more schedules.

Comment: Hi, this is just js and has very little to do with Angular or even typescript. I think you should add proper tags

Comment: Can you share more of context what you are trying to achieve? Is it like race of timers?